# how to loop through Json result object inside object array

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I have a json object returned from my c# code. I am looping through the result in jquery.

everything is working fine BUT this is just a sample object. actual object is way much bigger and the current method which i am using is not very clean. could any one help me how do i loop through object inside object.

Here is my code..

**Response JSON**

```
[
   {
      "ProductId":7363,
      "ProductName":"Brisk Waterproof Men\u0027s Jacket",
      "ProductDetails":{
         "ImagePath":"/assets/productimages/017/017271_BLA_MENS_BRISK_JACKET_-(10).jpg",
         "ImageAltText":"BLACK:3",
         "ProductSummary":"Waterproof & taped seams\r\nHighly breathable fabric\r\nDouble storm flap\r\nMultiple pockets",
         "MSRP":{
            100.00      
         },
         "Price":{
           65.00
         }
      },
      "StatusCode":"Success",
      "ErrorMessage":null
   },
   {
      "ProductId":6941,
      "ProductName":"Fizz Kid\u0027s Waterproof Jacket",
      "ProductDetails":{
         "ImagePath":"/assets/productimages/016/016792_BLA_FIZZ_KIDS_JACKET_SS13_4.jpg",
         "ImageAltText":"BLACK:5",
         "ProductSummary":"Waterproof & taped seams\r\nDetachable hood\r\nAdjustable hem\r\nMultiple pockets",
         "MSRP":{
              150.00
         },
         "Price":{
             129.00
         }
      },
      "StatusCode":"Success",
      "ErrorMessage":null
   }
]
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.btnGo').on("click", function (e) {
    console.log("click event fired");
    var jsonData = [{
        ProductId: "7363"
    }, {
        ProductId: "6941"
    }];
    $.ajax({
        url: "/JsonHelper/ProductHelper.ashx",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                console.log('Object: ' + key);
                var details = value.ProductDetails;
                var MSRP = value.ProductDetails.MSRP;
                var price = value.ProductDetails.Price;
                console.log(details);
                console.log(MSRP);
                console.log(price);
                $('.resultJson').append("<br />");
                $.each(value, function (k, v) {
                    $('.resultJson').append(k + ":    " + v + "<br />");
                    if (k == "ProductDetails") {
                        if (details != null) {
                            $.each(details, function (dk, dv) {
                                $('.resultJson').append(dk + ":    " + dv + "<br />");
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    if (k == "MSRP") {
                        if (MSRP != null) {
                            $.each(MSRP, function (mk, mv) {
                                $('.resultJson').append(mk + ":    " + mv + "<br />");
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    if (k == "Price") {
                        if (price != null) {
                            $.each(price, function (pk, pv) {
                                $('.resultJson').append(pk + ":    " + pv + "<br />");
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                $('.resultJson').append("----------------  ------------------");
            });
        },
        error: function (data, status) {
            console.log("FAILED:" + status);
        }
    });
});
```

I am very confused about $.each and dont know how to efficiently loop through mulitple objects.

Comment: Have you looked into using for loops instead of each? It could help you here. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: you are doing it right, what else do you need?

Comment: If you hope to get any answer, you should only show the relevant code instead if just giving your whole jquery event handling ;)

Comment: @spart4cus: I think in this case, the jQuery is small enough to ignore.

Comment: I have 4 levels of object inside 1 json object. and i thought if there is any other way of looping through objects inside object. everytime i have to check for if condition and and then null condition for evey object.

Comment: You should be able to just use the objects directly, and not loop at all, except that you need one outer loop because you start with an array.

Comment: You also need to fix this: `"MSRP": {100.00}`.  Presumably it should be just `MSRP: 100.00`, and similarly for Price.  But if it's an object, then you need, say, `"MSRP": {"val": 100.00}`.  Or if this happens to be the only value in what could be a multiple-valued array, you might want `"MSRP": [100.00]`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: taken note of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that if your data is consistent, then you're better off working directly with the format and not looping through everything to find keys and values.  I created **[a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/gGgRk)** using your code (skipping the AJAX part.) and for contrast **[another Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/gGgRk/2/)** with the following code:

```
var success = function (data) {
    var product, i, len, $output = $('.resultJson');
    for (i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        product = data[i];
        console.log('Object: ' + i);
        var details = product.ProductDetails;
        var MSRP = product.ProductDetails.MSRP;
        var price = product.ProductDetails.Price;
        console.log(details);
        console.log(MSRP);
        console.log(price);

        $output.append("<br />");
        $output.append("ProductId: " + product.ProductId + "<br />");        
        $output.append("ProductName: " + product.ProductName + "<br />");        
        $output.append("ProductDetails: " + "<br />");
        if (details) {
            $output.append("ImagePath: " + details.ImagePath + "<br />");
            $output.append("ImageAltText: " + details.ImageAltText + "<br />");
            $output.append("ProductSummary: " + details.ProductSummary + "<br />");
            $output.append("MSRP: " + MSRP + "<br />");
            $output.append("Price: " + price + "<br />");
        }
        $output.append("StatusCode: " + product.StatusCode + "<br />");        
        $output.append("ErrorMessage: " + product.ErrorMessage + "<br />");        
        $('.resultJson').append("----------------  ------------------");
    }
};
```

I think the latter is much easier to understand.  Of course all this is moot if your data is less consistent.

Comment: +1 and accepted your answer for the working Fiddle. My code was also working BUT i was looking for a cleaner solution which you provided..